# sending email when clicking a link

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django. I am developing my own website where in one portion, I want to use referral code. I have successfully generated unique referral codes. In mention,each referral code is storied in the database with the associated user while the user signing up in my website; that's okay. But I want to send this unique referral code with an email.In the user profile page ,a simple anchor tag will be given to the user and will asked  to click the link to get an email.The email will contain the referral code of the associated user.

as example...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title%}
 Profile page
{% endblock %}
{%block content%}
<!-- ==== Referral Code ==== -->
    <div id="greywrap">

        <a href = {% %}>Click here to get your referral code to your email</a>
    </div>






 {% endblock %}
```

here you can see  that there is a anchor tag where the user is asked for click the link to get the email.Now how can i integrate the send_email() function with the link to send an email.i know that the send_email is used to send email.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to properly send the e-mail by clicking on a link in the template, you should do the following:

1. Create a method in your **view**.

   In this method you may need to do something to obtain the user ID as an input (from the [HTTP request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user), probably) and get the referral code from the database; then send the e-mail with the code provided by wavemode. This would mean something similar to:

   `def send_referral_code(request):
       user = request.user
       # Do some work to obtain the referral code from the request.user object
       # Do some work to obtain the e-mail from the request.user object
       from django.core.mail import send_mail
       send_mail('Subject here', 'Message with referral code', 'from@example.com' ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)`
2. Link this method from the **urls** file in your app.

   The following is untested, but should give you an idea: `url(r'^send_referral_code/$', 'user.views.send_referral_code', name='send_referral_code')`. This means that the method `send_referral_code` can be found in the `views` module, inside the `user` app.
3. Refer the previous url from your **template**.

   This is done with a simple `{% url send_referral_code %}`, this time inside the `href` of your link.

Note that this assumes that no input parameter is passed. If you needed some, be sure to add it to the view and urls and finally pass it as the argument in the template, right after the method name (between the `%`'s)

There are several basic tutorials, e.g.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view. You may find examples of url's defined with parameters in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Django function [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#send-mail):

```python
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: My question is how can i apply this send_mail function? wavemode